# iOS movie player controls jump to middle of player at end of video

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

My application uses HTTP Live Streaming to play video files. We have run into a problem where as soon as the stream ends the player controls jump from the bottom of the player to the middle as seen in this screenshot (http://postimage.org/image/1dvr9u338/). Is this expected behavior and if not, any thoughts on what is happening?

If the application plays a non-live streaming video, such as an mp4, everything works fine. But as soon as we play a live-streaming video (m3u8), such as Apple's sample streaming video (http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8) this issue occurs.

The application supports iOS 4.2+ and the issue occurs on every version. I have tested this with a brand new project that just embeds an MPMoviePlayerController's view and plays the video. Below is some sample code that loads the contentURL, embeds the view, and plays the video.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];
     moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 600, 400);
     [self.view addSubview:c.view];

    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [moviePlayerController play];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```